# Docker MongoDB image - How to specify credentials other than in the compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, security, docker-swarm, databases

I'm using this docker image https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/. That image provides a way of initializing a mongodb root database user with env variables which I can specify in the compose file as follows:

```
environment:
  - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=db
  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
```

It seems storing the password in config files is not very secure. How can I use more secure ways (i.e. docker secrets) to init the root user in this case? Same thing for initdb files, which I need to copy to the container and may as well contain more credentials.

I wonder if anyone here found a more secure way of handling this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secrets support for mongo is built in. You can see in that [image's entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/58bdba62b65b1d1e1ea5cbde54c1682f120e0676/3.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L34-L37) that if you add `_FILE` to end of username/password values it will pull from those secret files.

As for .js files, if you're storing decrypted passwords in those files, you'd need to make a custom entrypoint script or something that will take envvars you're passing in for which secrets to use and run a `jq` or `sed` on the file to replace I guess. You can store the .js files themselves in a secret as longas its smaller than 500Kb (max size of a secret).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution I've used in cases like this - I utilize [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro.html) to manage Docker containers, and [Ansible Vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/vault.html) to store secrets for those containers.

#### Ansible Playbook to run MongoDB container

Your `playbook.yml` may look something like this:

```
- name: run mongodb docker container
  docker_container:
    name: mongo-container
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    env:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: "{{secret_db_name}}"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "{{secret_db_user}}"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "{{secret_db_pass}}"
```

- As you might notice, the [`docker_container`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/docker_container_module.html) syntax looks a lot like what you'd write in a Docker Compose YML file.
- The difference is that your *secrets* are managed in variables (the `{{}}` is [Ansible Jinja2 variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#using-variables-about-jinja2)).
- Here's a list of [Ansible Modules](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/list_of_cloud_modules.html#docker) for interacting with Docker.

#### Vault file to manage your `mongodb` secrets

The `vault.yml` file would contain the definitions of your secrets in an encrypted form.

```
secret_db_name: foodb
secret_db_user: foo
secret_db_pass: bar@123
```

You can use [`ansible-vault` commands](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/vault.html) to create encrypted files  (for e.g in version-control).

#### Getting it all together

When you want to run your Docker container, you would run an Ansible command

`ansible-playbook playbook.yml --ask-vault-pass`

Which would

- ask you for your vault password file,
- decrypt the vault file and pass the variables to the playbook;
- run the docker mongodb container with your secret credentials

All whilst ensuring your credentials are not publicly visible.

#### Notes

- I've used this approach to provision Dockerized databases on remote managed servers in a declarative way.
- You introduce one more tool, a 'wrapper' around Docker. In my experience DevOps *toolchains* work better than utilizing single tools. However, this may or may not be a constraint for you.